# How to pass queries using Axios in Vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, axios

How can I pass query paramenters using Axios such that I can get the query in my backend code using `req.query.email`. This doesn't seem to work:

```js
this.$http.post(this.$BASE_URL + 'agents/auth/create-password', {
  data: { password: this.password },
  params: {
    email,
  },
})
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

What I'm getting from my api is `req.body.data` and `req.body.params`.

Comment: Based on `this.$http` I don't think you are using axios instead you are using vue-resource. Please read https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md.

Comment: I'm using axios, just using a prototype I set in my main.js

Comment: Sorry for the urgent conclusion. Could you post more code about that implementation? Since maybe there is something wrong about parameters.

Comment: What additional implementation do you ned to know? I explained what I want to do above

Comment: I want to know about how you implement `this.$http` which wrap axios or you just use `Vue.prototype.$http = axios`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const querystring = require('querystring');
axios.post('http://something.com/', querystring.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }));
```

For more information have a look on https://github.com/axios/axios#query-string.